# Not receiving iOS push notifications while using the application

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

There is a particular app which I use on an iPhone 5S. It sends notifications from time to time. I am able to receive notifications when I am logged in but not using the application.

But I am not receiving the notifications while I am using the app. Why not?

Comment: Is the app not even realizing that the event even happened, or is the problem that you wanted notifications to look and act the same whether or not the app is running? For example Facebook notifications when not running the app can be dialogs or banners, but when I'm running the app, I just get a red notification dot on one of the icon buttons, letting me know I have more messages or posts to read. So it's not that Facebook isn't getting the notifications, it's just that the way of bringing them to the user's attention is different when the app is running vs when it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications aren't shown if the app is already open. There is a way in the API for the app to know if it receives a notification when it's open but it's up to the app to manually display it. So for this particular app, I guess it just hasn't implemented that piece of functionality.